# Error in cbind(admission$GPA, admission$GMAT)[train, ] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, error-handling

I keep getting an error message that I don't know how to fix when I try running the code below.

```
# load data
admission <- read.csv("admission.csv")

# Load the library
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)

# Divide the data into training and test sets
admit <- admission[1:5,]
notadmit <- admission[32:36,]
border <- admission[60:64,]

train <- admission %>%
  filter(!row_number() %in% c(1:5, 32:36, 60:64))
test <- rbind(admit, notadmit, border)

library(class)
train.X = cbind(admission$GPA, admission$GMAT)[train, ]
test.X  = cbind(admission$GPA , admission$GMAT)[!train , ]
train.Group = admission$Group[train]
```

Error in cbind(admission$GPA, admission$GMAT)[train, ] :
invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: Please add some dummy data next time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot subset `cbind(admission$GPA, admission$GMAT)` (a matrix) with `train` (a dataframe). Instead, `train` should be a vector of integers to subset by position:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create dummy data
admission <- tibble(
  id = 1:100,
  GPA = runif(100),
  GMAT = runif(100),
  Group = runif(100)
)

# Divide the data into training and test sets
admit <- admission[1:5, ]
notadmit <- admission[32:36, ]
border <- admission[60:64, ]

# find row numbers for training data
train <- admission |> 
  anti_join(admit, join_by(id)) |> 
  anti_join(notadmit, join_by(id)) |> 
  anti_join(border, join_by(id)) |> 
  pull(id)

# subset data
train.X = cbind(admission$GPA, admission$GMAT)[train, ]
test.X  = cbind(admission$GPA , admission$GMAT)[!train , ]
train.Group = admission$Group[train]
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>